# How to prevent overwriting when copying files

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a script to copy files from one directory to another. I can't figure out how to do it when the destination folder doesn't have a file with the same name as the file to paste. Ideally the user should be able to pick whether to skip or to overwrite. Here's my code:

```
require 'fileutils'
mydir = '/path_to_my_dir_here/*.{JPG,jpg}'
pic_names = Dir[mydir]

puts
print "Copying #{pic_names.length} pics:"

pic_number = 1
pic_names.each do |filename|
dest_folder = '/path_to_my_destination_folder/My_bg_pics'
FileUtils.cp(filename, dest_folder) 
    pic_number = pic_number + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `preserve` option with Fileutils.cp